# Zoom in Basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I'm using pyqt4 and basemap among others packages to produce an application. 
While I use the zoom in Basemap, it's changes the figure size.
This just happens when I plot something using basemap and I think this is because basemap doesn't allow any distortions. 
Is there any way to keep the figure size fixed?

Comment: Does this happen for other backends? Can you please post some code that reproduces the problem (a minimal example)?

Comment: I tried to post a figure but I don´t have permission yet. It doesn´t matter the code. 
- If you use Basemap to plot, when zomming, the figure size is modified. 
- If you plot any other thing just with matplotlib the size is not modified by the zoom process, but you have a distortion in the axes to keep the figure with the same size. 
I didn´t find a way to zoom with basemap but keeping the same figure size, such as happens when you use the zoom tool in google maps or arcgis for example.